# Перейти из fragment на браузер, почему может не работать моя кнопка?

Tags: android, ui

Вот, собственно, код. Я хочу по кнопке на форме перейти на сайт.

```
    public class SixActivity extends Fragment {
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.six2, null);
        return v;
    }
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("https://www.google.com"));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

six2.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="174dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/two_step" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="@string/button_free" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Логах только это:

```
Skipping entry 0x7f0a0004 in package table 0 because it is not complex!
```

Comment: Не совсем по теме, но очень, Очень, ОЧЕНЬ не рекомендую использовать онклики в xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В фрагментах не работает такой способ установки обработчика для кнопок(через xml). Точнее там это по идеи делается как-то муторно. Поэтому самый просто способ - ручками вытащить кнопку(getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button1) и установить обработчик ей(setOnClickListener()).